# predeploy for PersistenceUnit failed in JBOSS with toplink essentials

Tags: jpa, jboss5.x, persistence-unit, toplink-essentials

When i am trying to deploy the product in jboss 5.
I am using toplink-essentials for the JPA 1.0.

This product is running successfully on tomcat 6.

But in jboss it is showing errors.

I am trying to deploy the product through Eclipse IDE.

Error output :

```
19:38:27,983 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=persistence.unit:unitName=#Entity state=Create
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0 (Build b40-rc (03/21/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [Entity] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:615)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:178)
at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitDeployment.start(PersistenceUnitDeployment.java:301)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:59)
at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:150)
at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:241)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:109)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:221)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54)
at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:774)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:540)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:121)
at org.jboss.deployers.vfs.deployer.kernel.BeanMetaDataDeployer.deploy(BeanMetaDataDeployer.java:51)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: Exception [TOPLINK-28018] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0 (Build b40-rc (03/21/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: predeploy for PersistenceUnit [Entity] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException.predeployFailed(EntityManagerSetupException.java:212)
... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.xml.XMLHelper.parseDocument(XMLHelper.java:623)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProcessor.readStandardMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:369)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.metadata.MetadataProcessor.readMappingFiles(MetadataProcessor.java:339)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.ejb.cmp3.persistence.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:344)
at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.ejb.cmp3.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:584)
... 61 more

........
........
........

15:37:39,014 WARN  [HDScanner] Failed to process changes
org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS):

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
Deployment "persistence.unit:unitName=#Entity" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:993)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:939)
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:873)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.checkComplete(MainDeployerAdapter.java:128)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:369)
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Here is my persistence.xml file...

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

<persistence-unit name="Entity" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <non-jta-data-source>java:/iport</non-jta-data-source>

    <class>env.model.masters.IptNotifications</class>
    <class>env.model.masters.IptNotificationslines</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase" />
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="xx" />
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="xx" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I am using Struts 2.1.x, spring 1.2.x, jpa 1.0, toplink-essentials 2.0

Please help me to solve the problem...

Edited on 29/04/2013:

Hello Please any body can help me...

I can understand one thing, that there is some thing wrong in persistence.xml and it's data.

After so much googled, i had found some solutions.... like....

1) Remove the "private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;" from all pojos.

2) There should not be white space in persistence.xml inside  tag.

3) Change the JTA datasource from NON-JTA datasoucre.

I had changed all things as per the above mentioned points.

But still i am getting the same error.

My updated peresistence.xml is..

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="Entity" transaction-type="JTA">

    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <jta-data-source>java:/iport</jta-data-source>

    <class>env.model.masters.IptNotifications</class>
            <class>env.model.masters.IptNotificationslines</class>

            <properties>
                <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver"
                     value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
                <property name="toplink.jdbc.url"
                     value="jdbc:sqlserver://x.x.x.x:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase" />
                <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="xx" />
                <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="xx" />
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Please verify the problem. and suggest me a possible solution.

I also have the orm.xml file.

The code is like below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
version="1.0">
<persistence-unit-metadata>

    <persistence-unit-defaults>

        <schema>MySchema</schema>

        <catalog>MyDatabase</catalog>

    </persistence-unit-defaults>

</persistence-unit-metadata>
</entity-mappings>
```

Please verify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring when TopLink Essentials is trying to load the default orm.xml file.  Do you have one?  Check that your file is valid and its namespace etc. are correct.  If you don't have one, you could trying adding one.

Also try to upgrade to the latest TopLink Essentials patch release, or upgrade to EclipseLink, which replaced TopLink Essentials since 2008.

Comment: Hi James. Yes i have the orm.xml file. right now i cannot upgrade my EclipseLink, because i had done lot of work.

Comment: Just now i had updated my orm.xml in above problem. please verify once and tell me that is it have any problem in that??

Comment: finally i ugraded from toplink-essentials to eclipselink. and the above problem had resolved. Thank you james...

Answer (score 0):

The exception doesn't explain much, but at least in Glassfish, transaction-type must be set to JTA instead of RESOURCE_LOCAL in the persistence.xml file, because as a full blown Java EE Application Server, it wants to have JTA transactions ready to use for EJB's and to inject container managed EntityManagers.

If that's also the problem with JBoss and you are using Spring, there are workarounds like changing the name of persistence.xml file to something else, so JBoss doesn't try to load the persistence unit that is already being handled by Spring.

Comment: Hi German, i had tried as per your suggestion, i had changed the `transaction-type="JTA"` and modified the tag `<non-jta-data-source>` to `<jta-data-source>`. But again it is showing same kind of error. I had removed the `transaction-type="JTA"` tag still there is no change. The error in same stage. Please help me to solve the problem.